# Android Studio: TableRow from pattern does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Android offers table implementing in xml-file via `TableLayout` as a table and `TableRow` as rows., something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

However, when `TableRow` is dragged from pattern in Android Studio, the following text appears:

```
<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Such form of `TableRow` seems to be useless because there is no place to insert row views. Is it a bug of Android Studio, or I don't understand how to use such form of `TableRow`?

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow

> A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout. If a
>   TableRow's parent is not a TableLayout, the TableRow will behave as an
>   horizontal LinearLayout.

so you should only use it within TableLayout

**EDIT1**
When you have layout open you can switch between Design and Text views, correct?When in the Design view drag and drop TextView from Palette on the TableRow, it generates following xml in the Text view

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Of course, `TableRow` is used as a child of `TableLayout`, it is not a question. The question is about a form of `TableRow`: Android Studio pattern generates it in a tag like `<TableRow .... />`, and there is no place for row views.

Comment: once you have the TableRow you can drag e.g. the TextView or ImageView etc. in to the TableRow and will appear in a specific row. Or do you want to use the TableLayout in the way the RecylcerView is used?

Comment: Stachu, where to drag `TextView` if `TableRow` is in a form of single tag?

Comment: Stachu, thanks for clarification, I used this technique too. The little problem is that pallete generates something like  `<TableRow .... />` (no separate closing tage), whilst  `<TableRow .... > ....  <TableRow .... />` (opening tag and closing tag separately).  This is like a bug of Android Studio, and user have to edit generated  `<TableRow .... />` each time manually,

Comment: which Android Studio are you using? in 3.5.3 the closing tag is not generated for empty TableRow, but it's added after you add some items to it

Comment: Android Studio 3.5.3. Where should the item be added to? I tried to insert it between`<TableRow` and `/>`, but a closing tag was not added automatically.

Comment: the closing tag gets generated after you drag and drop in the DesignView, into the ComponentTree, same as described here
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php?title=A_Kotlin_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial&mobileaction#.EF.BB.BFAdding_the_TableLayout.EF.BB.BF_to_the_User_Interface